# Subclassing a final class; or, a Degenerate Decorator

Tags: java, decorator, subclass, final

I have a number of different representations of the same kind of object; let's call it a Thing.  "Thing" is a marker interface.  ThingFormat0, ThingFormat1, ThingFormat2 etc. are all JavaBeans that implement Thing.  (Because they are JavaBeans, a JSON marshaller automatically converts them to and from JSON automatically.)  ThingFormat1 has just a few members like name and id.  ThingFormat2 has URI links to other Things.  In ThingFormat3 has ThingFormat1 representations of those other things etc.

The JSON serializer knows how to convert a URI automatically.  (It works for any class where you can use toString() and the constructor ClassName(String string) to convert.)

I want to have a ThingFormat0 that behaves like a URI but implements the marker interface Thing.

```
public class ThingFormat0 extends URI implements Thing {}
```

This does not work because URI is a final class and can't be subclassed.

The only way I can think of to do this is by making a decorator (a very degenerate sort of decorator as it doesn't add any functionality to URI).  This is easy in some "duck-typed" languages but more of a pain in Java, because I have to wrap a URI and implement all the methods of URI that I need.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two simple ways I can think of:

- If you use Eclipse, you can have delegate methods for any field generated automatically.
- Copy the source of URI into a new class named ThingURI.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason the class can't use composition instead of inheritance?

```
public class ThingFormat0 implements Thing {
  private final URI uri;

  public ThingFormat0(String uri) { this.uri = URI.create(uri); }

  public ThingFormat0(URI uri) { this.uri = uri; }

  public URI getUri() { return uri; }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return uri.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: When Thing is a member of my Response class, the JSON serialization of Response is {"thing":{"uri":"http://whatever"}} instead of {"thing":"http://whatever"}.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot subclass a final class.  Period.

In the case of URI, it is almost certainly final for security reasons; i.e. to stop someone from breaking sandbox security by supplying a sneaky subtype of URI that (for example) allows it to subvert access control.

So yes, you'll need to use a wrapper or decorator or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// base class that handles delegation
class BaseThing implements Thing {

   BaseThing(String uri) { ... }

   BaseThing(URI uri) { ... }

   URI getURI() { ... }

   ...
}

class ThingFormat0 extends BaseThing {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're finding this is difficult because your `ThingFormat` types *are not* URIs. They expose URIs and can correspond to URIs, but that does not make them URIs. Perhaps you're pining for *implementation inheritance*, but *interface inheritance* fails here because this is not a proper *is-a* relationship; it fails the [*LSP*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Consider, for example, whether a `ThingFormat` has a scheme or a fragment component, or if one can be resolved against some base URI. Those are facets and operations of URIs that don't have much to do with `ThingFormat`, whatever it happens to do.